# Do the Google Docs Embed Viewer or the Office Embed Viewer support BLOB or DATA URLs?

Tags: javascript, blob, powerpoint, embed, data-uri

Talking about these:
https://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=

https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=

I want to show a .ppt or .pptx in an iframe but I don't use file URLs in front-end, I only have access to a blob url or a data url. I kind of ruled out Blob on my own as in that it's not going to work but I was wondering if anyone ever got a Data URL to work?

And I was also wondering about how secure these embeds are to use for business related purposes? I know third party is never really a good idea...

Would love to hear from you guys, documentation if you guys can find it is also welcome (I couldn't).

Comment: Your question is off-topic here. Stack Overflow is for questions about programming. Please post your query at http://answers.microsoft.com or Super User.